# Exercício de dicionário

Tags: python, dicionário, entrada-de-dados

Não estou conseguindo resolver esse exercício. Preciso que a letra que indica o tipo de serviço (E,R ou F) seja indicada na mesma linha das demais informações, contudo, de acordo com a letra inserida, as informações pedidas são diferentes, aí não sei como fazer.

Exercício: Gerenciamento de lavajato

Entrada:  Cada linha da entrada começa com uma letra ‘E’, ‘R’ ou ‘F’, indicando o tipo de
transação a ser realizada.
Se a transação for do tipo ‘E’ (entrar), o resto da linha conterá o primeiro nome do
cliente (sem espaços), e qual o tipo de serviço a ser realizado (‘cera’ ou ‘lavagem’).
Caso a transação for ‘R’ (retirar), o resto da linha conterá somente o primeiro nome
do cliente a ter o carro retirado.
Por fim, a última linha da entrada será sempre do tipo ‘F’, indicando o fechamento
do lava-jato.

Saída: Para cada transação do tipo ‘R’, seu programa deve imprimir qual o último serviço
que foi realizado no carro em questão. Caso não houver nenhum carro cadastrado
sob o nome requisitado, imprimir ‘Usuário não cadastrado’.

Exemplo:

Entrada:

E Walter cera

R Heisenberg

R Walter

F

Saída:

Usuário não cadastrado

cera

Meu código:

```
dicionario = {}

c=0

while c==0:

    letra = input()

    if letra=="E" :

        nome, serviço = input().split()

        dicionario.update({nome:serviço})

    elif letra== "R":

        nome1=input()

        if nome1 in dicionario.keys():

            print(dicionario[nome1])

        else:

            print("Usuário não cadastrado!")

    elif letra=="F":

        c=c+1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode antes de dar o split verificar qual será operação, é só observar o primeiro caractere da string do input (entrada[0])

Veja se não é mais ou menos isso que você está tentando fazer:

```
dicionario = {}

c=0

while c==0:

    entrada = input("Digite o texto de entrada: (EX: E Walter cera)")

    if entrada[0] =="E" :

        opcao, nome, serviço = entrada.split()

        dicionario.update({nome:serviço})

    elif entrada[0] == "R":

        opcao, nome = entrada.split()

        if nome in dicionario.keys():
            print(dicionario[nome1])
        else:
            print("Usuário não cadastrado!")

    elif entrada[0] =="F":

        c=c+1
```

Comment: Exatamente isso! Obrigada!